# Calling a function in a route with phpmailer

Tags: php, controller, namespaces, slim

Let me see how best i can explain what i am trying to do along with code example. I am just doing some clean up of my code and want to figure out the best way to move things around. I have a form and when i click submit it send me and email that works fine (using phpmailer, installed it using composer)

Working code below:
This is my post that is called after the submit which works fine. I want to move the php mailer code into a separate namespace i created.

```
    $app->post('/', function ($request, $response) {

  $mail = new PHPMailer;                             // Enable verbose debug output

  $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.stackmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Username = 'info@nicolauslawson.com';                 // SMTP username
  $mail->Password = 'miya1234';                           // SMTP password
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
  $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

  $mail->setFrom('info@nicolauslawson.com', 'Mailer');
  $mail->addAddress('nicolaus.lawson@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient

  $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
  $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
  $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

  $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
  $mail->Body    = '    <div class="container">
        <p>Name: '.$request->getParam('name').'</p>
        <p>Number: '.$request->getParam('number').'</p>
        <p>Dept: '.$request->getParam('dept').'</p>
        <p>Date of last leave: '.$request->getParam('singedate1').'</p>
        <p>Date of last resume: '.$request->getParam('singedate2').'</p>
        <p>Date Request: '.$request->getParam('datefilter').'</p>
      </div>';
  $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

  if(!$mail->send()) {
      echo 'Message could not be sent.';
      echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
      echo 'Message has been sent';
  }
});
```

Creating the namespace below using psr-4

```
    "autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app"
  }
```

Then i move the code to a file called Mailer.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Mailer
{
  public function sendMail()
  {
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.stackmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'info@nicolauslawson.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'miya1234';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('info@nicolauslawson.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('nicolaus.lawson@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient

    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = '    <div class="container">
          <p>Name: '.$request->getParam('name').'</p>
          <p>Number: '.$request->getParam('number').'</p>
          <p>Dept: '.$request->getParam('dept').'</p>
          <p>Date of last leave: '.$request->getParam('lastleave').'</p>
          <p>Date of last resume: '.$request->getParam('lastresume').'</p>
          <p>Date: '.$request->getParam('datefilter').'</p>
        </div>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
  }
}
```

And finally in my route i have

```
$app->post('/', '\App\Controllers\Mailer:sendMail');
```

Just trying to figure out where i am going wrong and why after moving the code it doesn't work when i call the function from Mailer.php I know i got the psr-4 and namespace working because when i remove all the code and put below:

```
   <?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Mailer
{
  public function sendMail()
  {
    return 'Working';
  }
}
```

It works fine. Any suggestions? Sorry for such a long question guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're attempting to invoke the class `PHPMailer` and your application will be trying to find this in `App\Controllers\PHPMailer`.

You will need to either [import the namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) or add a [global fallback](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php), then it should work fine.

Import namespace:

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use PHPMailer; // Import PHPMailer from global PHPMailer

class Mailer
{
    public function sendMail()
    {
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
```

Fallback to global:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Mailer
{
    public function sendMail()
    {
        // The leading \ tells PHP that the class is in the global namespace and not within this namespace
        $mail = new \PHPMailer;
```